# Is there an efficient way to share scripts between Airflow Deployments?

Tags: airflow

We have several Astronomer airflow deployments in production. Each deployment is based off its own git repo (some differences between each), however, they all use a core set of SQL scripts. Currently, if we need to update one of the core SQL scripts we need to update each and every airflow deployment (big pain and prone to copy paste errors).

Is there a way we can efficiently share these core SQL scripts in such a manner that we only need to update one repo and the changes are propagated to all deployments?

Comment: We have a DAG that downloads the repo as a ZIP file, extracts it to the /data directory and then rsync's to the /dags directory. Would a similar DAG be beneficial for your use case?

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar requirement and we are deploying the SQL scripts and other metadata files in object storage, So you can have a seperate CI/CD job to deploy SQL scripts to Object Storage like AWS S3 or Azure Data Lake, and the processing system can read the SQL files and execute.

If there any changes in the SQL scripts then we can only deploy the SQL scripts to Object Storage.